# How to kill apache prefork's child from PHP

Tags: php, apache

I'm using Apache 2.2 with prefork module.

I have a PHP script which eats a lot of memory. After this script finish I'm having apache process still eating a lot of memory.

Is it possible from PHP script to kill Apache process which is serving current PHP script?

`apache_child_terminate()` function only works with Apache 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may kill the script by the posix extension. (should be enabled by default)

```
posix_kill(posix_getpid(), 9); // or SIGKILL if you have pcntl also
```